# Is it possible to use rbind with na values in r

Tags: r

I want to ask that I created an empty dataframe, and used rbind to bind a row of data into the dataframe. So that generated one row of data in the empty dataframe. But if there are NA values in the data from the rbind, and the dataframe was created to have double values.

```
df = dataframe(name=character(),day1=double(),day2=double(),day3=double(),day4=double(),...)
listdata = (2.3,1.1,NA,2,...)  #note there is just one NA here
df = rbind(df,c('',listdata))
```

Then, I got the warnings:

```
10: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "2") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Even though I add `stringAsFactors=F` in the code when creating the dataframe, it still has this warning. What is the problem? Is this because of the NA value in the list? Thanks.

Comment: That's not the error message you would get from R with that code.

Comment: Yes, because the dataset is big, I made a subset with similar structure.

Comment: Post the output of dput(.) for the small data. And always post the code you enter without the `,...` since that was obviously not what you did enter.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there are a lot of errors in your code, which makes it hard for us to answer your question.

There are two problems:

1) Creating a vector of data as you do with `listdata = c(2.3, 1.1, NA, 2, ...)` coerces all elements into the same class. So it won't necessarily fit well with your dataframe.

2) The function `data.frame` automatically converts `character` objects to factors. This is why you're getting the above error. Include `stringsAsFactors=F` in your `data.frame` argument

Comment: I added stringsAsFactors=F, but it still doesn't work. So you mean that this code: c(2.3, 1.1, NA, 2, ...), will generate a list of elements below the same class?

Comment: @Lily: Just because you create a dataframe with no factors does not mean that all other methods that work on dataframes (such as `rbind`) will necessarily honor that request. The rbind/cbind help page says that `cbind.data.frame` will honor an `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` parameter but it says nothing about `rbind.data.frame`.